# execute tasks synchronously in gulp

Tags: gulp

I have read online that 'run-sequence' will make sure all specified tasks will run synchronously. For some reason this is not true in my case. Am I missing something?

'convertSassToCss' is the task that does not work as intended

If I would run tasks 'cleanAllCss' and 'convertSassToCss' seperatelly, it would work.

The idea here is to first remove all css files from directory, then convert all sass files into css and place the into the cleaned dir

```js
/// <binding BeforeBuild='clean, min:css' Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
  rimraf = require("rimraf"),
  concat = require("gulp-concat"),
  cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  del = require('del'),
  runSequence = require('run-sequence');


var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.cssPath = paths.webroot + "css/*.css";
paths.cssOutputPath = paths.webroot + "css";

//sass
paths.sassPath = paths.webroot + "sass/**/*.scss";
paths.sassOutputPath = paths.webroot + "./css/file";

gulp.task("cleanAllCss", function (cb) {
    console.log("2 -- Removing all CSS files");
    del([paths.cssOutputPath + "/*.css"], cb);
    console.log("2 -- DONE - Removed all css files");
});

gulp.task("convertSassToCss", function (cb) {
    console.log("3 -- Converting all SASS files into corresponding CSS");
    gulp.src(paths.sassPath)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssOutputPath));
    console.log("3 -- DONE - Converting all SASS files into corresponding CSS");
});

//not working, should run in sequence
gulp.task("convertAllSassIntoCssMin", function (callback) {
    console.log("1 -- Converting all SASS files into corresponding min CSS files")
    runSequence('cleanAllCss', 'convertSassToCss', callback);
    console.log("1 -- DONE - Converting all SASS files into corresponding min CSS files")
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the result when you execute `convertAllSassIntoCssMin task? What is printed on the console?

Comment: It does not generate and output css files into the directory I have mentioned above. The console outputs 1,2,2,1, and finally Process terminated with code 0. 3 is never reached, but it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `cleanAllCss` task. The second parameter accepted by **del** is [options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del#delsyncpatterns-options), not the callback which you're trying to pass. The callback is never executed. Try running it manually when the removal is finished.

```
gulp.task("cleanAllCss", function (cb) {
    console.log("2 -- Removing all CSS files");
    del([paths.cssOutputPath + "/*.css"]).then(paths => {
        console.log("2 -- DONE - Removed all css files");
        cb();
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak to *run-sequence* as I haven't used it before.

However, you can run tasks in sequence by using **Gulp**'s task dependency feature, where a task will **NOT** run until it's dependencies have finished running.

**Your new tasks signatures**

1. *`cleanAllCss`* stays the same:

   `gulp.task("cleanAllCss", function (cb) { ... }`
2. *`convertSassToCss`* changes to:

   `gulp.task("convertSassToCss", ['cleanAllCss'], function (cb) { ... }`
3. *`convertAllSassIntoCssMin`* changes to:

   `gulp.task("convertAllSassIntoCssMin", ['convertSassToCss'], function (cb) { ... }`

This ensures that `convertAllSassIntoCssMin`  won't run until `convertSassToCss` has finished which in turn won't run until `cleanAllCss` has finished.

Refer to gulp [deps](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps):

> deps
>
> Type: Array
>
> An array of tasks to be executed and completed before your task will
>   run.
>
> gulp.task('mytask', ['array', 'of', 'task', 'names'], function() {
>   // Do stuff }); Note: Are your tasks running before the dependencies
>   are complete? Make sure your dependency tasks are correctly using the
>   async run hints: take in a callback or return a promise or event
>   stream.
>
> You can also omit the function if you only want to run a bundle of
>   dependency tasks:
>
> gulp.task('build', ['array', 'of', 'task', 'names']); Note: The tasks
>   will run in parallel (all at once), so don't assume that the tasks
>   will start/finish in order.